# Why isn't the background color changed in the following html page with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to learn html with bootstrap and css styling. And it's often quite confusing. Things don't seem to work the way they are supposed to as described. For example changing the background color which when googling seems very straight forward. However in the following code the background color doesn't change. By experimenting for half an hour with different variations I might get it to work but what I want to know is why it doesn't work in this example where I explicitly say that the body should have the background color #000000.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Portfolio page">
    <meta name="author" content="Christoffer Berg">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class = "active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid text-center bgim bgimg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid text-center bgim bgimg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1>About</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid text-center bgim bgimg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid text-center bgim bgimg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The styles.css file:

```
h1 {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

body {
    background: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matters:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

To

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
```